Reason for wreath product?
I read about imprimitive action and was told any imprimitive group is isomorphic to a wreath product of symmetric group on its block and symmetric group on the subscripts of its blocks. But why don't we take their direct product? Does it make sense to alter their scripts?

That's not right, an imprimitive action is a subgroup of the wreath product of the symmetric group on a block and the symmetric group on the set of blocks in a block system. We don't take the direct product because the result would not be true if you did that.
